# How can I retrieve all Note records for all Account using SOQL

Tags: soql, classic

How can I retrieve all Note records for all Accounts where notes are attached to accounts using SOQL

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

You can run a query similar to this:

```
Select {whatever fields you need} From Note WHERE Parent.Type = 'Account'
```

This will retrieve all Notes where the ParentId is of type Account